# scss - Usage of '~' in imports is deprecated - angular - vscode

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, sass

Since angular 13, using a tilde (`~`) to import SCSS files from the `node_modules`

close.component.scss

```
:host ::ng-deep {
    // Configuration
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";

    // Layout & components
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/close";
}
```

results in the following warning after running `ng build`:

> Warning: 'C:\repos\...\src\lib\components\close\close.component.scss' imports '~bootstrap/scss/close' with a tilde. Usage of '~' in imports is deprecated.

Changing this and removing the tilde is easy. But VS Code doesn't find the file anymore when
<kbd>ctrl</kbd> clicking the scss-path. It thinks it's located at

```
C:\repos\...\src\lib\components\close\bootstrap\scss\close
```

I've already tried [this change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72792200/8941307) but it changes nothing.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

### Edit

For those wondering why we need `:host ::ng-deep` around the `@import` statements, it scopes the styles within to the component. A good example here is the `bs-list-group` and `bs-list-group-item` which I use like this:

```
<bs-list-group>
    <bs-list-group-item>Cras justo odio</bs-list-group-item>
    <bs-list-group-item>Dapibus ac facilisis in</bs-list-group-item>
    <bs-list-group-item>Morbi leo risus</bs-list-group-item>
    <bs-list-group-item>Porta ac consectetur ac</bs-list-group-item>
    <bs-list-group-item>Vestibulum at eros</bs-list-group-item>
</bs-list-group>
```

The following scss imports in `list-group.component.scss`

```
// Configuration
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// Layout & components
@import "~bootstrap/scss/list-group";
```

Result in the following

[image: Bootstrap listview with scoped styles]

On the other hand:

```
:host ::ng-deep {
    // Configuration
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";

    // Layout & components
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/list-group";
}
```

Where `ng-deep` removes the component scopes, and `:host` is replaced with the attribute angular applies on the `BsListViewComponent` (in this case `[_nghost-bkg-c64]`). This lets the styles work for the entire `BsListviewComponent`, since the scopes were removed from the css selectors.

[image: Bootstrap listview with stripped scopes]

This actually DOES work...

Comment: Why are your imports in a selector ?

Comment: Because I'm using angular, this scss file is for a component and thus angular scopes these styles to the component. `.example` would become `*[_ngcontent-wcc-c60] .example` after the build. Adding `::ng-deep` removes these scopes right-hand side of it. This way, I'm able to make the bootstrap styles flow over multiple cooperating angular components

Comment: But angular material seems to do this [totally different](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/checkbox/checkbox.scss)...

Comment: This is wrong. Imports go to the head of the file, NOT inside the selectors.

Comment: @E.Maggini is right, and you're wrong about `this scss file is for a component and thus angular scopes these styles to the component` : imports are juste imports, they do not add content to your CSS file (it's `@include` that does that). Imports should go at the top of your code. Not that it resolves your issue, but I wanted to point it out ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to replace with the path to the css, something like :

```
@import node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins'
```

Before to do that, I recommande you to go on the bootstrap file that you want to import and get the relative path to the file.

The in your scss file replace the ~ path with the relative path.

Becarful to not include .scss file inside the path.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This compiles fine too, but it still doesn't allow me to ctrl+click the paths (`@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";`)

Answer (score 49):

1. In `angular.json` file
2. Add this below `build -> options`:

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
   // other options...
   "includePaths": [
     "./node_modules"
   ]
 }
```

3. Remove `~` in every import

*Take this warning with a grain of salt: It might be better to explicitly use the `node_modules/` prefix instead, especially if more than one person is working on this project.*

Comment: In my project I did not already have a `stylePreprocessorOptions` setting and I did not understand where to put it. After looking a bit, this should go into `build` -> `options` section, in my case I put it directly under the `"styles"` entry.

Comment: Yes, it should directly go under `build > options`.
Reference: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#style-preprocessor-options

Comment: If you don't want to add all node modules, you can add individual paths, e.g. for `~swiper/scss`, `~swiper/scss/autoplay`, etc., just remove `"./node_modules"` and add `"./node_modules/swiper"`. Add an entry for each package you want to include.

Comment: when I do this (after removing the tilde from `@import '~@angular/material/theming';`), I get "Cannot find mixin 'mat-elevation'" on a line like this: `@include mat-elevation(8);`

Comment: This still doesn't allow me to ctrl+click on the path

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface maybe it should be `@include mat.elevation(8);`