# SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import. - Angular upgrade

Tags: angular, sass, node-sass, angular-upgrade

Recently I updated my angular application to version 14 and after the upgrade, I am getting the below error.  The error is below

```
./src/assets/vendor/default/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
4 │ @import "~src/vendor/libs/ng2-nouislider/mixins";
```

Could anyone help to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tilde ~ in SCSS @use statement no longer resolving to node\_modules as of Angular 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70082698/tilde-in-scss-use-statement-no-longer-resolving-to-node-modules-as-of-angular)

Comment: Could you solve the issue?

Answer (score 45):

For Angular 15. remove tilde symbol (~) from the path.

Comment: Bless you kind stranger

Comment: This actually works, thank you! I suggest anyone having this error message after upgrading Angular to use this, it works.

Answer (score 8):

There are two options for resolve it:

- use `node_modules` instead of `~` tilda symbol  as shown
  `@import node_modules/..../mixins`
- Or add `node_modules` to `angular.json` file as below

```json
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [
    "src", "./node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I prefer to use the first one.

Comment: replacing ~ with node_modules worked for me!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with Angular 15 but the error only appeared in build and not locally.

~ (tilde) is no longer to be used since Angular 13 and is being deprecated.

I fixed the error replacing @import with @use in every file, as written here:
[sass at-rules import](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and couple of days I found below solution that works for me.
add relative path
@import '../../../node_modules/@angular/material/theming' ;