# Can't find stylesheet to import @import '@angular/material/theming';

Tags: angular

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Can't find stylesheet to import.
╷
24 │ @import '@angular/material/theming

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Can't find stylesheet to import.

Comment: As the error says, it probably error from import path, can you show how you import it? for example: @import '@angular/material/theming' ;

Comment: Also check this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/74611743/11762647

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't just throw your error messages at us but give us a little explanation about what you want to achieve, your configuration, etc. At least, ask a concrete question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a little how-to. On the one hand, this will make it easier (or possible at all) for us to help you solve your problem, on the other hand it makes us feel less mis-used as robots...

Comment: @import '@angular/material/theming'; This import is not working for angular 17 and angular material 17